# R Multiple Dataframe Column Matches to Populate Column

Tags: r, dplyr, match, left-join

I have a dataframe 'df1' that looks like:

```
structure(list(MAPS_code = c("SARI", "SABO", "SABO", "SABO", 
"ISLA", "TROP"), Location_code = c("LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-",
"LCP-"), Contact = c("Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", 
"Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall"), Lat = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "51.23"), Long = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "-109.26")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And a second dataframe 'df2' that looks like:

```
structure(list(MAPS_code = c("SAFR", "SAGA", "ELPU", "ISLA", 
"SABO", "SATE", "QUST", "SARI", "PANA", "COPA", "LOAN", "GAPA", 
"MELI", "CAGO", "PINO", "GABO", "RIJA", "FILA", "AMIS"), Lat = c(8.765833, 
8.751389, 8.768611, 8.835833, 8.801111, 8.808333, 8.815, 8.827778, 
8.781667, 8.778333, 8.783333, 8.800833, 8.790278, 8.754444, 8.844444, 
8.801389, 8.786667, 8.785278, 8.952222), Long = c(-82.94277, 
-82.951111, -82.95, -82.963056, -82.917222, -82.924444, -82.923889, 
-82.924167, -82.896944, -82.955833, -82.938611, -82.972222, -82.967222, 
-82.925833, -82.97, -82.972222, -82.964722, -82.976111, -82.833333
), Contact = c("Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", 
"Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", 
"Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", 
"Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", 
"Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall"
), Location = c("LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", 
"LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", 
"LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

How can I make populate each row of 'Lat' and 'Long' of df1 from 'Lat' and 'Long' of df2 when 'Contact', 'Location', and 'MAPS_code' of the corresponding rows match between df1 and df2? So that the result of df1 looks like:

```
structure(list(MAPS_code = c("SARI", "SABO", "SABO", "SABO", 
"ISLA", "TROP"), Location_code = c("LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", "LCP-", 
"LCP-"), Contact = c("Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", 
"Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall", "Chase Mendenhall"), Lat = c("8.827778", "8.801111", "8.801111
", "8.801111", "8.835833", "51.23"), Long = c("-82.92417", "-82.91722", "-82.91722", "-82.91722", "-82.96306", "-109.26")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note, if there are already data in Lat and Long, I don't want them deleted or written over with NAs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
We could use `dplyr::coalesce` to retrieve the values which is not `NA` among the two pairs of `Lat` and `Long`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  rename(Location = Location_code) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('MAPS_code', 'Contact', 'Location')) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), as.double)) %>%
  mutate(Lat = coalesce(!!!(select(., starts_with('Lat')))), 
         Long = coalesce(!!!select(., starts_with('Long')))) %>%
  select(!contains('.'))


  MAPS_code Location          Contact       Lat       Long
1      SARI     LCP- Chase Mendenhall  8.827778  -82.92417
2      SABO     LCP- Chase Mendenhall  8.801111  -82.91722
3      SABO     LCP- Chase Mendenhall  8.801111  -82.91722
4      SABO     LCP- Chase Mendenhall  8.801111  -82.91722
5      ISLA     LCP- Chase Mendenhall  8.835833  -82.96306
6      TROP     LCP-        Tom Jones 51.230000 -109.26000
```

Comment: Another option if column names don't match, which can be useful as well. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Is there a way to write the script so that if anything already exists in Lat and Long it doesn't get overwritten?

Comment: Provide a sample data and then I will take a look at it.

Comment: I've updated the question to better represent what I'm asking for.

Comment: Check my updates. The first `mutate` function is not necessary if both of your `Lat` and `Long`s are of the same data type.

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to [@Anoushiravan R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911430/8366499), but I'd suggest removing unnecessary variables before joining, rather than wrestling with the variable names generated by duplicate columns:

```
df1 %>%
    select(-Lat, -Long) %>%
    left_join(df2, by=c('MAPS_code', 'Location_code'='Location', 'Contact'))


  MAPS_code Location_code          Contact      Lat      Long
1      SARI          LCP- Chase Mendenhall 8.827778 -82.92417
2      SABO          LCP- Chase Mendenhall 8.801111 -82.91722
3      SABO          LCP- Chase Mendenhall 8.801111 -82.91722
4      SABO          LCP- Chase Mendenhall 8.801111 -82.91722
5      ISLA          LCP- Chase Mendenhall 8.835833 -82.96306
```

Passing a named vector element to the `by=` argument (for example `'Location_code'='Location'`) lets you join on non-matching variable names. The name on the left side of the `=` is the name in the first data.frame (or the one piped in), while the name on the right side is the name in the second data.frame.

Also, note that this will add the new variables onto the end (right) of the joined data frame. If you wanted to match the order of variables in `df1` (that wouldn't apply here, since the order is the same), you can use `select` to reorder the variables:

```
... %>%
    select(one_of(names(df1)), everything())
```

`names(df1)` gets the variable names from df1 in order. By putting it in `one_of`, a variable missing in the final data.frame will give a warning instead of an error. Ending with `everything`, will ensure that no variables are lost, and any variable not in df1 will be stuck on the end.

Comment: This is great. I didn't ask for this, but users should know that this method places Lat and Long at the end of the dataframe, rather than their original position. Not a big deal, but maybe worth mentioning. Thank you!